# can't bind to IsEnabled property of ToggleButton using caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to bind the IsEnabled property of a ToggleButton with no success.

once the NotifyOfPropertyChange is fired, I'm getting the following exception:

`Value does not fall within the expected range.`

Using a simple Button, the above configurations works as expected.

I wonder if there any workaround for that one?

Thanks

UPDATE:

well it took me a while to pinpoint the problem, but finally managed to understand the behavior:

I've created a simple tester where I use a button to enable/disable a `ToggleButton`.

when the `ToggleButton` control does not contain anything, all works properly; however, after adding sub controls to it (in our case I just added a `StackPanel`) an exception  is raised:

`Value does not fall within the expected range` - right after NotifyOfPropertyChange() is called.

Here is the problematic view I'm using:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="SayHello"  Grid.Column="1"  IsEnabled="{Binding HasValue}"  Height="190">
        <StackPanel x:Name="sp"> </StackPanel>
    </ToggleButton>
    <Button x:Name="Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

The `ViewModel`:

```
    private bool _hasvalue;

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get { return _hasvalue; }
        set
        {

                _hasvalue = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => HasValue);
        }
    }

    public void Click()
    {
        HasValue = !HasValue;
    }
```

Any way to workaround that one? - the platforms is WP8.

Comment: Could you please post the xaml in question, along with the object/property you're binding to?

Comment: The control which is your sub controls, might be a child for another control.. Please check that...

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't replicate the error from the example above, is there additional information in your `ViewModel`?

you should also be able to get the effect you want (although I'd still be interested to see the root cause of your error), by using the `Caliburn.Micro` conventions. Is `x:Name=sp` causing anything to be bound?

If you have a method `SayHello`, with a `UI` element bound to the method via a convention: `x:Name="SayHello"`

You can create a bool property on your `ViewModel` called `CanSayHello`, which `Caliburn.Micro` will use to Enable/Disable the control; although you will have to call `NotifyPropertyChanged` when that property changes (so the `UI` is aware and can update the control).

E.g.

```
<!-- Your existing Control, Note `IsEnabled` is not bound -->
<ToggleButton x:Name="SayHello" Height="40">

// On your ViewModel
public bool CanSayHello
{
    get
    {
        return HasValue;
    }
}

public void Click()
{
    HasValue = !HasValue;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSayHello);
}
```

[Some additional info.](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions)